# elif statement does not work

Tags: python, indentation

I'm sorry for this but I'm a complete beginner and no matter what I try it's just going wrong. Can anyone give me just a small idea of whats going wrong with my elif statement so I can keep at it? (Also I know there's the current mistake of 1% at the 0%, was just testing the theory)

```
one = (1)
three = (2)
four = (4)
five = (5)
seven = (7)

stampduty = int(input("Enter amount of residential property"))

if stampduty >= 1 and stampduty<=125000:
    add = (stampduty*one/100.0)
    addamount = stampduty + add
    print("Stamp Duty percent 0% \nyour stamp duty amount is", addamount)
elif:
    add =  add = (stampduty*one/100.0)
    addamount = stampduty + add
    print("Stamp Duty percent 0% \nyour stamp duty amount is", addamount)
```

Comment: what do you expect `add =  add = ...` to do ?

Comment: That's not in the actual programming, just something I've acidentally done while putting it here :)

Comment: Also, why do you have your values contained in parentheses?

Comment: Guyz, you're missing the biggest question of all! `three = (2)`?

Answer (score 7):

`elif` requires a condition, just like an `if` statement. If you want an unconditional block, use `else`:

```
if stampduty >= 1 and stampduty<=125000:
    add = (stampduty*one/100.0)
    addamount = stampduty + add
    print("Stamp Duty percent 0% \nyour stamp duty amount is", addamount)
else:
    add =  add = (stampduty*one/100.0)
    addamount = stampduty + add
    print("Stamp Duty percent 0% \nyour stamp duty amount is", addamount)
```

Comment: You might want to propose some more changes: `if 1 <= stampduty <= 125000:` and `add = stampduty * one / 100.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `else` instead of `elif`. 
In `elif`, like in `if` you need to pass a condition.